# Why using jQuery.data() with firefox gives "Error: Permission denied to access property"?

Tags: jquery, firefox

This happens always when trying to change a data-attribute on an element. 
It means setting a data-attribute the first time works fine, but it is impossible to change the value ? 
It is simple to test it, even in firebug. See the image below.

[image: Changing a data-attribute fails in Firefox]

In all the other reported cases of this Error-message, it has something to do with iFrames, but this has nothing to do with it.

Hope someone has any info about this.

Comment: Well.. works for me is all i can say..

Comment: Yes, It works like expected: http://jsfiddle.net/kx4F6/ [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) Do you use `$(document).read()`?

Comment: Ok, thanks, then it may be my Firefox only. I will try it from some other computers. (I am using Firefox 19, on Ubuntu)

Comment: Just to wrap it up, Thanks to the replies, found that it is only a weird bug related to **my** Firebug actually. This error occurs only when Firebug is up an running.